# How to implement and install Icomoon and Fontello icon packs in Drupal 7?

Tags: theming

**I am trying to get Fontello and Icomoon icon packs installed properly.**

I look in the backend and it says import for Fontello and Icomoon.

I have downloaded the packages, but importing creates an error.

I have manually downloaded and extracted them, put them in my libraries and:

```
Renamed folder: Fontello
```

And

```
Renammed folder:  Icomoon
```

But not found under status report, not even as missing. I have installed the Icon API module and enabled it.

Additionally, Fontawesome installed correctly and is showing ok in status report but it stil shows this error:

```
The Font Awesome library could not be found.Please make sure that     fontawesome was download & extracted at sites/all/libraries/fontawesome directory.Please check README.txt for more details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it figured out.

1. Go to Fontello website.
2. Drag and drop Icons you need in the box on top.
3. Save file as Zipped, don't do any renaming or extracting.
4. Go to admin/config/media/icon/import
5. Give it a title and import the zipped file you just downloaded.

The icons will then show up on the drop down when adding them to articles or wherever.

Additionally, the help files for Fontello are [here](https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/Help).

Comment: Not sure if that is changed in the Drupal 7 version, but I am unable to use a zip file. Must be tar, bz, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Icon API modules for [Fontello](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontello) and [Icomoon](https://www.drupal.org/project/icomoon)?  This should be easy to set up.

First you install [Icon API module](https://www.drupal.org/project/icon), then the provider modules (linked above). Then you go the respective websites (http://www.fontello.com/ and/or https://icomoon.io) and select the icons you need for your project. Basically you create an own "font" with this selection and download it as an archive. Which is the one you upload in the import dialog of the Icon API configuration page (admin/config/media/icon).

Comment: yes I installed both modules, not clear from what URL to download and then import files from

Comment: Just saw you figured it out already. Good!